# Clearing past undo action menu (Undo Rename, Undo Delete etc) Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

Sometimes I am moving/deleting/renaming files. After that I can press Ctrl+Z and return them to the previous state. Sometimes I press Ctrl+Z accidently(at the wrong spot). I was thinking if I can write some kind of a script(bat file) or something that will clear this history that is stored in the RAM (I know I can reboot my PC and the history will be deleted). I thought that the history is stored in the clipboard (isn't it)? I tried  `cmd /c "echo off | clip"` but it didn't work. Can you help me? (Some links would be helpful (I didn't really know how to google it))

Answer (score 0):

As you might imagine, all of us will occasionally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> accidentally. If I do that while I am working on something important, I ensure that I slow down the pace of my typing to avoid a recurrence.

Beyond that, when accidents like that happen you should be able to simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to redo the action that you just "undid."

For future reference, Microsoft maintains a comprehensive list of [Windows keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) that you might find beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I also want something to **clear undo history** but not found any software to do that.

#### Use delete file > empty recycle bin.

As I known, Windows will be clear undo history if

1. I delete some file(s) to recycle bin.
2. And then empty recycle bin.

So, I created simple **.bat** (batch) file to do this.

**WARNING!**: This will be use delete > and empty recycle bin method. It will be **dangerous** if you have some files in recycle bin and don't want to permanently delete them yet. Becareful!

This is not good solution for you but just work.

1. Download [cmdutils](http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/) from maddogsw.com website.
2. Extract files into somewhere on your Windows. For example: **D:\myportable\cmdutils**
3. Add that path (**D:\myportable\cmdutils**) to Windows environment `PATH` to be able to access `Recycle.exe` and `Bin.exe` from anywhere.
4. Copy and paste code below to **clearundo.bat** or any name you want.

```
@echo off
REM WARNING!: This will be use delete > and empty recycle bin method. 
REM It will be dangerous if you have some files in recycle bin 
REM and don't want to permanently delete them yet.

REM https://tecadmin.net/create-filename-with-datetime-windows-batch-script/ set date/time as file name

set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%

echo .> %SUBFILENAME%.txt
echo A file was created.

REM ########################################
REM delete a previously created file.
Recycle -f %SUBFILENAME%.txt
echo Deleted a file to recycle bin.

REM ########################################
REM empty recycle bin.
Bin /empty /force
echo Emptied recycle bin.
```

5. Now, whenever you want to clear undo history, just run this command `clearundo`. Don't forget to read **WARNING!** above.

I hope that I can find someone created a simple software for clear undo history without have to do what I do here.